# A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, delayed-job

I am trying to send email from action mailer with delayed_job gem in rails.
I am calling method of action mailer from after_create callbacks

in demo model

```
after_create :send_mail
def send_mail
  DemoMailer.to_client( self).deliver
end
```

in demo_mailer

```
def to_client( demo)
  @demo = demo
  mail(:to => demo.email, :subject => "Confirmation")
end
handle_asynchronously :to_client
```

it shows an error

```
ArgumentError in DemosController#create

A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message
```

then I change

```
def send_mail
  DemoMailer.to_client( self).deliver
end
```

to

```
def send_mail
  DemoMailer.delay.to_client( self)
end
```

it did not show any error but I did not get any mail also.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests: you are missing either a `return-path`, `sender` or `from` field. Setting a `from` field is not difficult:

```
mail(:to => demo.email, :from => 'webmaster@your-domain.com', :subject => "Confirmation")
```

See the [ActionMailer#mail documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-mail) for more information.

Comment: I am using default :from => 'test@mydomain.com' at the top, without delayed_job it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting `from` at top:

```
class FoobarMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: SomeClass.email_variable
  #...
```

You may give a try this:

```
class FoobarMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: -> { SomeClass.email_variable }
  #...
```

---

Or send it just like @Veger mention:

`mail(:to => demo.email, :from => 'webmaster@your-domain.com', :subject => "Confirmation")`